# JSSOR slider - how to change these properties?

Tags: javascript, css, image, slider, gallery

I've implemented that kind of jssor slider
https://www.jssor.com/demos/nearby-image-partial-visible-slider.slider

You see a main image at the front and the part of the previous and the next image. How to resize that slider to see the previous and the next image of the gallery fully, without a cut? I need to expand that to the full width. In options of this slider you can change max width, but doing that you resize the whole slider. I need to expand it to the full width but without changing the height of the window.
Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the 'slides' container width to 3 times of slide width.
If the slide width is 500, you can change the 'slides' container width to 1500.
In this manner, you can see 3 slides display in the 'slides' container.

Comment: Yes, thank's for the answear :) I found the right proportion. The slider width must be half of the max width.